# Is it possible to compose URL that forces browser to download file instead of play it?

Tags: url

Let say we have some file at `http://somedomain.com/somedir/file.mp4`.

When I send such URL to someone, I would like that browser start download, not play automatically.

Is it possible to compose URL in such manner to give browser instruction to start download instead of play it? With some parameter included maybe?

Comment: not the url but if you send them a link with word  'Download' in it, I think it will download. Example <a href='myfile.mp4' download>Download the file</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that by just sending the URL to someone.
What you can do is create a simple file which forces the user to download the file by setting the mime type of the response to octet/stream, which is the way of telling the browser the file can not embedded.
Below is an example in PHP taken from [this website](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?244007-RESOLVED-Force-download-of-MP3-file-instead-of-streaming).

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```